# How to read information from shared memory in Java?

Tags: java, shared-memory

Is it possible (and if yes - how) to read information from a Shared Memory on Widows system?

I would like to get details from a Shared Memory block, created by `Core Temp` program, as described [here](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/developers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a JNI module. There is no standard Java means of accessing Windows shared memory.